# Group By , COUNT(*) and JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

When running the SQL below, any placemark_types.id that doesn't have a id match in placemarks table does not return anything in the results. I'm trying to at least get a type_count of 0 back where there are no matching records in placemarks.

So if I have a placemark_types.name of 'Warning' and there are no 'Warning's in placemarks table, id like to get the columns `| 0 | 'Warning'|`

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS type_count, placemark_types.name
FROM  `placemark_types` 
JOIN placemarks ON placemark_types.id = placemarks.type_id
WHERE placemark_types.parent_id =0
GROUP BY placemark_types.id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL, by default, performs an `INNER JOIN`, where only rows with a record in both tables are returned.

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` to tell MySQL to return one side of the join even if the other side is empty. In this situation, you'd want a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to always specify what type of join you are doing.  By default it is using an inner join.  An inner join will only show items that have a match in both tables.  In your example, you want all the records returned from the placemark_types and zero-to-many of the records from the placemarks table that match.

To do this just use a left join as shown below.  The left join always returns all the records from the left side (placemark_types) and only the matching records from the right side (placemarks).  Next lets get rid of the `COUNT(*)` and use COUNT(placemarks.type_id), because we don't want to count all the rows, just the ones with matches in the placemarks table.  Else you would get 1 even when their where zero matches because it would still be counting the placemark_types.

```
SELECT COUNT(placemarks.type_id) AS type_count, placemark_types.name
FROM  placemark_types
LEFT JOIN placemarks ON placemark_types.id = placemarks.type_id
WHERE placemark_types.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY placemark_types.id
```

To understand this better, run the query without the `GROUP BY`.  You'll see that even when their are no entries in the placemarks table, you will get the fields from the placemark_types table and nulls for the placemarks fields.  Since the `COUNT(placemarks.type_id)` will not count nulls, this will give you the correct number.